# Type safe plugins for a data processing pipeline

Tags: haskell

I am writing a Haskell library for writing Discord bots, and I would very much like to be able to let the users of my library write type-safe plugins.

Discord sends me messages which roughly look like follows:

```
data EventType
    = FooEvent
    | BarEvent
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Payload
    = Payload
    { eventType :: EventType
    , payload :: Maybe Value
    }
```

The `eventType` parameter uniquely determines what JSON object gets sent in the `payload` parameter, and for certain `EventType`s it's also possible that there is no payload at all.

What I'm interested in accomplishing is for the users of the library to declare on the type level which kind of event they wish to process, and then using the type system to demand a function which has the appropriate type. I would then like to be able to take all of these plugins, regardless of their types, and treat them as homogenous entities and essentially just take whatever messages I'm currently processing, running it through a list of all the plugins in the system and each plugin will attempt to convert the `payload` JSON value into the appropriate type, and run its code if the conversion succeeds.

For sake of example, we can use the following payload types:

```
data FooPayload = FooPayload {foo :: String}
    deriving (Read, Eq, Show,  Generic)
instance ToJSON FooPayload
instance FromJSON FooPayload

data BarPayload = BarPayload {bar :: String}
    deriving (Read, Eq, Show,  Generic)
instance ToJSON BarPayload
instance FromJSON BarPayload
```

What I have done so far is to create a type class with an associated type:

```
class FromJSON (PayloadType ev) => Convertible (ev :: EventType) where
    type PayloadType ev :: *
    convert :: Value -> Maybe (PayloadType ev)
    convert = parseMaybe parseJSON

    -- run :: Proxy (PayloadType ev) -> Plugin ev s -> Value -> IO ()
    run :: Plugin ev s -> Value -> IO ()
    run p v = undefined
        -- case convert v of
        --     Just v' -> runPlugin p v' -- doesn't typecheck because of non-injectivity of type families
        --     Nothing -> return ()
```

And the accompanying instances

```
instance Convertible 'FooEvent where
    type PayloadType 'FooEvent = FooPayload

instance Convertible 'BarEvent where
    type PayloadType 'BarEvent = BarPayload
```

Along with the following types:

```
data Plugin (ev :: EventType) s
    = Convertible ev => Plugin
    { initializePlugin :: IO s
    , runPlugin :: PayloadType ev -> IO ()
    }


newtype RunnablePlugin = RunnablePlugin (Hide Plugin)
data Hide f = forall (ev :: EventType) s. Convertible ev => Hide (f ev s)
```

I can then define a couple of plugins and actually treat them the same:

```
fooPlugin :: Plugin 'FooEvent ()
fooPlugin =
    Plugin
    { initializePlugin = return ()
    , runPlugin = \_ -> putStrLn "This is a foo plugin"
    }

barPlugin :: Plugin 'BarEvent ()
barPlugin =
    Plugin
    { initializePlugin = return ()
    , runPlugin = \_ -> putStrLn "This is a bar plugin"
    }

plugins :: [RunnablePlugin]
plugins =
    [ RunnablePlugin $ Hide fooPlugin
    , RunnablePlugin $ Hide barPlugin
    ]
```

I would then ideally be able to do the following

```
runPlugins :: Value -> [RunnablePlugin] -> IO ()
runPlugins val plugs = do
    forM_ plugs $ \(RunnablePlugin (Hide p)) -> do
        run p val
        return ()
```

So, ideally, running `runPlugins  (toJSON (FooPayload "foo")) plugins` would print `This is a foo plugin`.

Everything type checks except for the commented definition for `run` in the type class.

I think I mostly understand what the issue is -- I'm kind of dropping type information in order to treat the things as the same, and recovering that type information isn't possible with what I have. That is my intuition, anyway, but I'm not very comfortable with this kind of "type wrangling".

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with what we have in GHC/Haskell, or is this something I need dependent types for?

The code in its entirety can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cd9ef58f99f116ba77643eee7acc2158).

Comment: `TypeApplications` can dodge some injectivity errors. Maybe try that? Or, you can just use a data family, because `FooPayload` isn't very different from `PayloadType FooEvent` (you may want to shorten the names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is how I would do this. It is substantially different from your existing code, and it's not the only way. I just think doing it this way will make future code easier to write.

```
data EventType = FooEvent | BarEvent
data Payload :: EventType -> * where
  FooPayload :: { foo :: String } -> Payload FooEvent
  BarPayload :: { bar :: String } -> Payload BarEvent
```

We have singletons for `EventType`. If you don't know what these are, it's essentially a hack to emulate dependent types:

```
-- use a library like singletons to avoid this tedium
-- singletons will call this Sing
data SEventType :: EventType -> * where
  SFooEvent :: SEventType FooEvent
  SBarEvent :: SEventType BarEvent
-- these classes sort of "factor out" the need for classes later
-- the class will be named SingI and its method sing under singletons
class KEventType (ev :: EventType) where kEventType :: SEventType ev
instance KEventType FooEvent where kEventType = SFooEvent
instance KEventType BarEvent where kEventType = SBarEvent
-- singletons generates these, too
-- SomeSEventType would be called SomeSing EventType; it's isomorphic to EventType
data SomeSEventType = forall ev. SomeSEventType (SEventType ev)
toSing :: EventType -> SomeSEventType
toSing = _obvious
fromSing :: SomeSEventType -> EventType
fromSing = _obvious

-- A Payload ev contains enough information to determine ev
payloadEventType :: Payload ev -> SEventType ev
payloadEventType FooPayload {} = SFooEvent
payloadEventType BarPayload {} = SBarEvent
```

For any `EventType` `ev`, we have a corresponding `Value -> Parser (Payload ev)`

```
parseEventPayload :: forall ev. SEventType ev ->
                     Value -> Parser (Payload ev)
parseEventPayload SFooEvent = _
parseEventPayload SBarEvent = _
```

And we can also make a `FromJSON`:

```
-- example of previous comment
-- this instance can be just the one instance instead of one per EventType
-- parseEventPayload will get warnings if it doesn't cover everything
-- and other good things
instance KEventType ev => FromJSON (Payload ev) where
  parseJSON = parseEventPayload kEventType
```

Now, we define the type of the messages (type and payload) Discord sends you:

```
data Message = forall ev. Message (Payload ev)
-- in singletons
-- newtype Message = Message (Sigma EventType (TyCon Payload))
```

This is a dependent pair: a `Message` "contains" an `EventType` `ev` and a `Payload ev`. The `EventType` needs no direct runtime representation, because the magic of GADTs means that a `Payload ev` is enough to determine `ev`. (`singleton`'s `Sigma` will represent `ev` as an `SEventType ev`, because it doesn't know better, but I'm writing this out manually and *do* know better.) Presumably, you get `Message`s as JSON:

```
instance FromJSON Message where
  parseJSON v = f . toSing =<< parseEventType v
    where parseEventType :: Value -> Parser EventType
          parseEventType = _
          -- find the payload inside the bigger value without parsing
          payload :: Value -> Parser Value
          payload = _
          f :: SomeSEventType -> Parser Message
          f (SomeSEventType ev) = Message <$> (parseEventPayload ev =<< payload v)
```

`Plugin` is unchanged:

```
data Plugin event s = Plugin
  { initializePlugin :: IO s
  , runPlugin :: Payload event -> IO ()
  }
```

But `RunnablePlugin` must remember the event type:

```
data RunnablePlugin = forall ev s. RunnablePlugin (SEventType ev) (Plugin ev s)
```

And you can take the first argument implicitly

```
runnablePlugin :: KEventType ev =>
                  Plugin ev s -> RunnablePlugin
runnablePlugin = RunnablePlugin kEventType
```

Now, your `run` doesn't seem quite right. Presumably, what happens is that Discord sends you some JSON with an event type and a payload. You deserialize that into a `Message` (which deserializes both the type and payload). You shouldn't be passing `Value`s around after this point, because that's just inefficient. There are four possible variants of `run`. You can either take a typed `Payload` or an existential `Message`, and you can take a `Plugin` or a `RunnablePlugin`. `runPlugin` fills the "all known types niche", so this `run` will be all existential. First, we need equality on the singletons:

```
-- singletons generates this under the name (%~) if EventType derives Eq
sEventTypeEq :: SEventType l -> SEventType r ->
                Maybe (l :~: r)
sEventTypeEq SFooEvent SFooEvent = Just Refl
sEventTypeEq SBarEvent SBarEvent = Just Refl
sEventTypeEq _ _ = Nothing
```

Then

```
run :: Message -> RunnablePlugin -> IO ()
run (Message py) (RunnablePlugin pge pg) = case sEventTypeEq (payloadEventType py) pge of
  Just Refl -> runPlugin pg py
  Nothing -> return ()
```

`runPlugins` is the simplest bit

```
runPlugins :: Message -> [RunnablePlugin] -> IO ()
runPlugins = traverse_ . run
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I actually managed to whip something up that works with data families, but it's not optimal as it requires me to carry around a `Value` and defers their parsing until a plugin actually needs it, which makes it hard to find bugs in the data type definitions/parsing logic. 

I tried the singleton approach, except I used the library, but I admit I'm a bit out of my depth here and I've run into the issues you can see in my code: https://gist.github.com/b6f30da2b2bad01066ba36920fc5f672

(continued in another comment)

Comment: My code, as you can see, shows a bit of a different picture than what I asked about, as there are actually two parameters in the message that determine the payload. 

For certain opcodes, there is no event parameter, and then the opcode determines the payload. For other opcodes, the event parameter is present and is used to determine the payload. 

I'm not sure if my issues are because of this additional parameter. 

I'll mark your answer as the solution, as it is essentially exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @identity Your `RunnablePlugin` has both `SingI`s and `Sing`s. These will be duplicates. You generally want to stick to using `Sing` for actual code and wrap it with implicit `SingI` versions if you want. `SomeMessage` doesn’t need the `SingI`s at all, since the `Payload` already contains that information. If you actually needed them, there’s a function that turns a `Sing a` into a `SingI a` somewhere. You’ve also defeated `payloadEventType`. The purpose is that it can extract the `Sing` from a `Payload`, but you cheated and took it from the context. `run` needs to check opcode equality too.

Comment: @identity You can post another question if you are really confused. Perhaps you may want to look at some other examples, too.